# When I compile the Python code below, I get IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Tags: python

When I compile the Python code below, I get IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level,how can i solve this issue

```
def staffView(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render(request, 'staff.html', {})
    elif request.method == "POST":
        print(request)

        dev_name = request.POST['dename']
        print("developer name: ", dev_name)

        dev_id = request.POST['dname']
        print("developer id: ", dev_id)
        
        developer = Developer.objects.create(developer_name=dev_name,developer_id=dev_id)
        developer.save();
        print("developer created")

    def index(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        print("returning index")
        return render(request, 'index.html')

    def assignmentView(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render(request, 'assignment.html', {})

    elif request.method == "POST":
        print(request)
        #process your form data
        #and save it to your db
        assign_id = request.POST['aidd']
        print("assignment id: ", assign_id)

        dev_id = request.POST['dname']
        print("developer id: ", dev_id)

        supp_staff = request.POST['sstaff']
        print("support staff: ", supp_staff)

        assign_date = request.POST['adate']
        print("assignment date: ", assign_date)
        ProjectAssign = ProjectAssignment.objects.create(assignment_id=assign_id,developer_id=dev_id,project_id=proj_id,support_staff=supp_staff,assignment_date=assign_date)
        ProjectAssign.save();
        print("ProjectAssignment created")

    def projectView(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render(request, 'project.html', {})
    elif request.method == "POST":
        print(request)
        
        proj_name = request.POST['pname']
        print("Project NAME: ", proj_name)

        proj_id = request.POST['pid']
        print("Project Id: ", proj_id)

        proj_type = request.POST['ptype']
        print("Project type: ", proj_type)

        stardate = request.POST['stdate']
        print("start date: ", stardate)

        endate = request.POST['edate']
        print("end date: ", endate)

        Financ_year = request.POST['yr']
        print("Financial year: ", Financ_year)

        descript = request.POST['desc']
        print("description: ", descript)
        
        Proj = Project.objects.create(project_name=proj_name,project_id=proj_id,project_type=proj_type,start_date=stardate,end_date=endate,Financialyear=Financ_year,description=descript)
        Proj.save();
        print("Project created")
```

Comment: Indent the code correctly. `def index(request)`, for one, should be indented the same amount as `def staffView`.

Comment: https://repl.it/repls/ApprehensiveLonelyArray#main.py

Comment: Often an indentation error can be caused by mixing spaces and tabs.  Make sure you haven't done that.

Comment: I think the OP needs to edit this and check that it matches exactly what they are running. I did a minimal edit to apply text formatting, aside from adding a code block I made an assumption that line 1 was to be unindented because otherwise the error message wouldn't match the exact one reported. But the remaining indentation problems would still give rise to a different error message than the one reported, and only the OP can fix this.

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.  Post the *full* error message and the minimal code needed to reproduce it.

Answer (score 1):

You're receiving the exception because you have incorrectly indented your code, simply move all your functions back. Your code should look like this:

```
def staffView(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render(request, 'staff.html', {})
    elif request.method == "POST":
        print(request)

        dev_name = request.POST['dename']
        print("developer name: ", dev_name)

        dev_id = request.POST['dname']
        print("developer id: ", dev_id)
        
        developer = Developer.objects.create(developer_name=dev_name,developer_id=dev_id)
        developer.save();
        print("developer created")

def index(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        print("returning index")
        return render(request, 'index.html')

def assignmentView(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render(request, 'assignment.html', {})

    elif request.method == "POST":
        print(request)
        #process your form data
        #and save it to your db
        assign_id = request.POST['aidd']
        print("assignment id: ", assign_id)

        dev_id = request.POST['dname']
        print("developer id: ", dev_id)

        supp_staff = request.POST['sstaff']
        print("support staff: ", supp_staff)

        assign_date = request.POST['adate']
        print("assignment date: ", assign_date)
        ProjectAssign = ProjectAssignment.objects.create(assignment_id=assign_id,developer_id=dev_id,project_id=proj_id,support_staff=supp_staff,assignment_date=assign_date)
        ProjectAssign.save();
        print("ProjectAssignment created")

def projectView(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render(request, 'project.html', {})
    elif request.method == "POST":
        print(request)
        
        proj_name = request.POST['pname']
        print("Project NAME: ", proj_name)

        proj_id = request.POST['pid']
        print("Project Id: ", proj_id)

        proj_type = request.POST['ptype']
        print("Project type: ", proj_type)

        stardate = request.POST['stdate']
        print("start date: ", stardate)

        endate = request.POST['edate']
        print("end date: ", endate)

        Financ_year = request.POST['yr']
        print("Financial year: ", Financ_year)

        descript = request.POST['desc']
        print("description: ", descript)
        
        Proj = Project.objects.create(project_name=proj_name,project_id=proj_id,project_type=proj_type,start_date=stardate,end_date=endate,Financialyear=Financ_year,description=descript)
        Proj.save();
        print("Project created")
```

Comment: No problem, be sure to mark it as a solution if it helped :)